# Hidden files and Folders in Chrome Extension zip files

Tags: google-chrome

`Chrome Store` requires to upload `ZIP` folder of `chrome` `extension`. But when I use compress utility of `Mac OS X`, some hidden files and folders are .DS_Store included in `ZIP` file.

Does `Chrome Store` delete this files when uploaded to the site or do I need to find a compression solution that will not pack hidden files and folders in `ZIP` files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your zip is unpacked and analyzed by the web store then becomes a crx file, however, since there is no way to know which files are going to be used at run time, **all files** are included back in the bundle.

There's an [issue related to this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103281), so you'd better to remove these files before creating your zip:

```
cd my_extension_folder
find . -type f -name '.DS_Store' -delete
zip -r my_extension.zip my_extension_folder
```